# el-get in a portable emacs configuration solution

Tags: emacs

`el-get` goes a long way in helping achieve a portable emacs configuration setup. The idea is to declare the packages you want in the emacs config file, push that file to a repo, and pull it on all the computers where you want an identical emacs configuration. This is how the code might look in `elisp`:

```
(setq my-packages (append '(el-get switch-window yasnippet ...)
    (mapcar 'el-get-source-name el-get-sources)))                  
(el-get 'sync my-packages)
```

`el-get` will make sure that the packages get automatically installed and properly initialized. However, my understanding is that when you dereference a package, it doesn't get uninstalled. And if you uninstall it manually, you'll have to do it across all the computers, also manually. In other words, el-get goes only half the way in achieving a truly portable solution. My question is if anybody has written elisp code that will uninstall the packages just by dereferencing them in init.el? Or whether I should look elsewhere for a fully portable declarative dependency management solution for emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use el-get in conjunction with some form of version control. That provides the portability, so that when you remove a package and commit the result to your repository, the package will also be uninstalled for the other instances once they have pulled those changes.

If you are leaving the package files to el-get to manage, then those *files* may still exist on the other copies after the package is removed from one instance but, provided that el-get's status and autoload files are in your repo, I think the *state* of each package should be correct.

Personally, I recommend committing all files to your repository after installing a package. That way when you remove a package, commit the changes, and pull those changes from another instance, both copies are in the same state.

Moreover, I would never trust the availability, consistency, or permanence of a remote source when it comes to setting up a new instance of my Emacs configuration -- the act of cloning my repository is all that should be required to obtain a working system.

So: use el-get for installing and updating packages, and use version control to make it portable.

Comment: Good answer. I will try the approach suggested. Instead of init.el, it's the whole .emacs.d that I will put under version control (git). Any special consideration to remote sources that are themselves git repos?

Comment: Yes, there's a trick you can use for that, known as [fake submodules](http://debuggable.com/posts/git-fake-submodules:4b563ee4-f3cc-4061-967e-0e48cbdd56cb). If you have a git-sourced package in `el-get/foo` then you can say `git add el-get/foo/` (the trailing slash is critical) to add all the contents of foo into the outer repository.

Comment: There *is* a down side to that, mind -- when you clone your repository, el-get won't know how to update that particular package, because the package's own repository won't be present. I'm not sure if you can combine fake submodules with *real* submodules to get the best of both worlds? I've never been sufficiently bothered by the issue to find out.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your insights. This should definitely get me started.

Answer (score 9):

I'm answering myself here because in the end I opted for an alternate solution.

phils' answer is still valid, but I found it troublesome to have the .emacs.d directory under version control, and to be fair I didn't want to bother with fake submodules.

What I did instead: I contacted el-get's maintainer, Dimitri, and presented him with the problem.

Dimitri said:

> I could see us adding an el-get-cleanup function that you would have to call with the current list of packages and that would el-get-remove any package already installed locally but not on the provided list.

```el
(el-get-cleanup my-packages)
```

> You could then use that from your user-init-file if you want to, or do
>   that as a routine every now and then.

With his guidance, I then wrote the function in question.

```el
(defun el-get-cleanup (packages)
  "Remove packages not explicitly declared"
  (let* ((packages-to-keep (el-get-dependencies (mapcar 'el-get-as-symbol packages)))
         (packages-to-remove (set-difference (mapcar 'el-get-as-symbol
                                                     (el-get-list-package-names-with-status
                                                      "installed")) packages-to-keep)))
    (mapc 'el-get-remove packages-to-remove)))
```

Ah, the joys of open source...

(See also my blog [post](http://danielsz.github.io/towards-a-declarative-dependency-management-s/index.html))

Comment: Thanks! I'm using both git and el-get for making my set-up portable. Wasn't sure how to declare packages that el-get should install on a new system, but your solution covers not only that but also removing packages that you no longer need. Brilliant!

Comment: By the way, this `el-get-cleanup` function has been added to the codebase : https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/commit/7ba81d6bf03817506b4bc5134b095a4c4fa8541b

Comment: @Daniel Szmulewicz: is your [blog post](http://danielsz.posterous.com/towards-a-declarative-dependency-management-s) available elsewhere? If so, please fix the link.